# What causes TrueCrypt to fail to load operating system during pre-test?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

I have been installing full disk encryption (FDE) on multiple computers and have record of 3 out of 163 computers failed.  They all failed at the exact same point and I have no clue why or how to bring them back up.  On completing the pre-test of a FDE the systems come back up stating no operating system found.  The only commonality between all the computers is Dell manufacturing.  Any idea the cause or a way to get back into the system without doing a complete system re-install?

Comment: are sure the hdd have not simply not failed?

Comment: No as we have been able to pull data off of the first two drives haven't done anything yet to the third.

Comment: Did you pull the TC recovery disk out of the optical drive before rebooting?

Comment: Did it after the reboot caused by the test procedure.